# Выполнение команды shutdown -r -f -t 0 -m \\<ipaddress>

Tags: windows, администрирование

На web-сервере расположен скрипт в котором прописана cmd команда "shutdown -r -f -t 0 -m \\ip address remote server".
Вопрос: если дёрнуть этот скрипт GET запросом с браузера клиентского компа, то от какого пользователя будет выполнена эта команда.

Comment: *Я правильно полагаю, что от system?* Нет. От имени того пользователя, под чьей учётной записью выполнено подключение к этому серверу.

Comment: Akina, извиняюсь, что написал без конкретики. В комментарии ответа от "romanown" я написал конкретику.

Comment: *В комментарии ответа от "romanown" я написал конкретику.* Удалите оттуда и переместите в сам вопрос. Никто ошмётки вопроса по комментариям собирать не будет.

Comment: Akina, переместил.

Comment: Команда прописана где-то в некоем коде. Если, к примеру, это PHP-код, то команда из него будет выполнена от имени того пользователя, от имени которого запущен процесс PHP. Вне зависимости от того, каким способом выполнение кода инициировано. Аналогично если там ASP - код будет выполнен от имени пользователя, под которым запущен IIS... и так далее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

если просто запустить командную строку или планировщик, то как было ранее написано от имени текущего пользователя. но если запустить от имени другого существующего в системе  или домене пользователя, то от него. но не от system. чтобы запустить от system, необходимо чтобы инициирующий запуск процесс был сам от него запущен. если бы знать причину такого вопроса и поставленные задачи, легче предлагать решения.